# nodejs UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined

Tags: nodejs, express, mongoose, multer

Hola estoy haciendo un proyecto en multer y resulta que al subir archivos me da el siguiente error
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined
En realidad no se que pasara y porque me dice que path esta indefinido aca les dejo un poco de código con la configuración de multer y como intento hacer el req.files.video[0].path

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: path.join(__dirname, '../public/video/upload'),
    filename: (req, file, cb, filename) => {
        cb(null, uuid() + path.extname(file.originalname));
    },
}); 
const upload = multer({
    storage:storage,
    fileFilter: function(req, file, cb){
        var ext = path.extname(file.originalname);
        if(ext == '.mp4' || ext == '.pdf'){
            return cb(null,true);
        }
        cb(new Error('Solo Archivos MP4 y PDF'));
    }
})
```

Esa es la configuración que le di a multer que utilizo para re-ubicar los archivos que se suben y asignarle con el packete uuid un nombre aleatorio en el directorio donde los guardo.

```
router.post('/rev/profesor/taller/:idTaller', upload.fields([{ name: 'video' }, { name: 'material' }]), async (req,res) => {
    await User.findById(req.session.passport.user, async (err, usr) =>{
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        if(usr.isProfesor == 'on'){
            const nuevoModulo = new Modulo();
            nuevoModulo.nombre = req.body.nombre;
            nuevoModulo.contenido = req.body.contenido;
            nuevoModulo.calendarizacion = req.body.calendarizacion;
            nuevoModulo.evaluacion = req.body.evaluacion;
            nuevoModulo.duracion = req.body.duracion;
            nuevoModulo.material = req.body.material;
            nuevoModulo.num_modulo = req.body.num_modulo;
            nuevoModulo.video_path = req.files.video[0].path;
            nuevoModulo.material_path = req.files.material[1].path;
    

            await nuevoModulo.save();
            console.log(nuevoModulo);
            await Taller.findById(req.params.idTaller, async (err, t) =>{
                let modulosLista = t.modulos;
                modulosLista.push(nuevoModulo._id);
                await Taller.findOneAndUpdate({_id: t._id}, {modulos: modulosLista});
            });
            res.redirect('/rev/profesor');
        } else {
            res.redirect('/rev/user');
        }
    });
});
```

Por ultimo esta es la zona donde yo hago el req.files.material[1].path y donde me da el error que tengo actualmente

Comment: ¿Ya has depurado tu variable? ¿Qué te muestra al hacer  `console.log(req.files)`? En todo caso que exista `req.files.material`, ¿el índice que usas es el correcto?. Saludos

Comment: ajam lo depure pero me mostraba el archivo que se subia, lo que hice fue primero esto req.files.path[1] y nada el mismo error, y con req.files[1].path lo mismo

Comment: No entiendo, ¿te mostraba que existe la propiedad `material` y que la misma es un tipo `array`?

Comment: yeap, eso me mostraba, o si era otra cosa era que no podia leer la propiedad path

Comment: inclusive cuando yo pruebo con `            nuevoModulo.video_path = req.files.path[0];
            nuevoModulo.material_path = req.files.path[1]; ` me dice que ` UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Comment: @MauricioContreras material es un objeto que yo muestreo en mi consola, que este tiene un atributo llamado path y solo ese atributo quiero guardar

Comment: no será que tienes que usar el índice `0` en vez de `1`? `req.files.material[0].path`

Comment: @hawks me dice que 0 esta indefinido

Comment: pues nose en la [documentación](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) pone que es `key-> array`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

El problema está en la lógica que implementas para trabajar con los archivos recibidos. Resulta que asumes que el formulario contiene ambos elementos (tipo `file`), cuando la realidad es que pudieras estar recibiendo sólo 1 o ninguno.

Por lo tanto, debes realizar la verificación pertinente antes de intentar trabajar con los elementos recibidos.

Por otro lado, el intentar acceder a un índice específico:

```
nuevoModulo.material_path = req.files.material[1].path;
```

puede causar problemas si el elemento de tipo `file` sólo contiene 1 archivo, en ese caso `material[1]` será `undefined`.

Por último tienes un error en la función que pasas al atributo `filename` del método `muter.diskStorage`. Actualmente tienes esto:

```
filename: (req, file, cb, filename) => {
    cb(null, uuid() + path.extname(file.originalname));
}
```

Sin embargo la [documentación](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#diskstorage) establece que la función recibe 3 parámetros: `(function (req, file, cb) {}`. Eso quiere decir que el parámetro adicional `filename`, en tu función, está de más. Por lo tanto, debes reescribir la misma de la siguiente forma:

```
filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, uuid() + path.extname(file.originalname));
}
```

**SOLUCIÓN**

La solución es simple, debemos implementar una lógica para capturar la posibilidad que el formulario no incluya campos de tipo `file`, es decir la posibilidad de que no se reciban archivos en la solicitud.

Además, debemos asegurarnos de obtener el índice adecuado de la lista de archivos recibidos.

En tu implementación capturas archivos de 2 elementos tipo `input`, uno llamado `video` y otro llamado `material`.

[Multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) nos provee de 3 métodos para controlar los campos tipo `file` enviados en la solicitud:

1. [`.single`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#singlefieldname): para manejar un único archivo. Esto quiere decir que si el elemento `input` contiene más de 1 archivo, se tomará sólo el primero de la lista y se guardará en `req.file` (nótese que el nombre es singular).
2. [`.array`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#arrayfieldname-maxcount): nos permite guardar todos y cada uno de los archivos en un elemento `input` de tipo `file` que soporte múltiples archivos. Si pasamos un segundo parámetro `maxCount` de tipo `number` entonces guardará sólo hasta la cantidad de archivos especificados por `maxCount`. Los archivos se guardan en `req.files` (nótese que el nombre es en plural) y con la siguiente estructura para cada elemento de la lista:

```js
{
  fieldname: <fildname - String>,
  originalname: <original file name - String>,
  encoding: <encoding type - String>,
  mimetype: <mime type - String>,
  destination: <path of stored file if diskStorage selected - String>,
  filename: <file name of stored file - String>,
  path: <path to file - String>,
  size: <size of file in bytes - Number>
}
```

3. [`.fields`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#fieldsfields): por cada campo (`field`) se creará una lista con los archivos encontrados en cada elemento de tipo `file` que sea enviado en la solicitud. El nombre de cada campo se usará como nombre para la lista de archivos. El objeto `req.files` tendrá un objeto con una propiedad para cada `field` recibido.

Aclarado esto, y viendo la forma en que recibes tu solicitud, estás usando la 3ra opción presentada.

Para determinar si realmente el formulario contiene los archivos en los campos `video` y `material` podemos hacer lo siguiente:

```js
if(req.files) {
  if(req.files.material && req.files.material.length) {
    console.log(req.files.material[0].path);
  }
  if(req.files.video && req.files.video.length) {
    console.log(req.files.video[0].path);
  }
}
```

Este bloque de código determina si existe el objeto `files` en la solicitud:

```
if(req.files) // devuelve 'true' si existe el objeto `files`
```

luego por cada uno de los campos, verifica que no solo el mismo exista, sino que a su vez contenga elementos:

```
if(req.files.video && req.files.video.length) // devuelve 'true' si existe el objeto re.files.video y si su tamaño es mayor que 0.
```

De esta forma nos aseguramos que podemos acceder a un elemento existente.

Tu código podría lucir de la siguiente forma:

```js
//...
if(req.files) {
  if(req.files.video && req.files.video.length) {
    nuevoModulo.video_path = req.files.video[0].path; // <-accede al primer elemento
  }
  if(req.files.material && req.files.material.length) {
    nuevoModulo.material_path = req.files.material[0].path; <-accede al primer elemento
  }
}
//...
```

De esta forma tu lógica es coherente y soporta los casos ya planteados al principio. Espero que esto te ayude a solucionar el problema.